# How to write a case statement with nested JSON in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, webhooks, easypost

I have an app that is integrated with the Easypost API (for shipping stuff, really cool). I'm using their tracking information webhooks to fire events in my app. I'm using ruby `case` statements to accomplish this.  Here's a link to Easypost's API doc: https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#webhooks

I would like to match my case statement to the result.status key value in the JSON. Initially I was using just the description, but I need it to be more specific. Take a look:

```
{
"id": "evt_qatAiJDM",
"object": "Event",
"created_at": "2014-11-19T10:51:54Z",
"updated_at": "2014-11-19T10:51:54Z",
"description": "tracker.updated",
"mode": "test",
"previous_attributes": {
  "status": "unknown"
},
"pending_urls": [],
"completed_urls": [],
"result": {
  "id": "trk_Txyy1vaM",
  "object": "Tracker",
  "mode": "test",
  "tracking_code": "EZ4000000004",
  "status": "delivered",
  "created_at": "2014-11-18T10:51:54Z",
  "updated_at": "2014-11-18T10:51:54Z",
  "signed_by": "John Tester",
  "weight": 17.6,
  "est_delivery_date": "2014-08-27T00:00:00Z",
  "shipment_id": null,
  "carrier": "UPS",
```

Here's the code I was using

```
class HooksController < ApplicationController
# to bypass CSRF token authenticity error
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

  def stripe
    #using easypost now as the webhook event
    case params[:description]
      # From EasyPost API https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#webhooks: 
      # tracker.updated: Fired when the status for the scan form changes
      when 'tracker.updated'
        @shipments = Spree::Shipment.where(transferred: false, state: "shipped")
        @shipments.each do |shipment|
          item_total = 0
          shipment.line_items.each do |item|
            item_total += item.product.price * item.quantity
          end  
          transfer = Stripe::Transfer.create(
            # Take 10% for ourselves from the total cost
            # of items per supplier(shipment)
            :amount => (item_total * (100 - shipment.supplier.commission_percentage)).floor,
            :currency => "usd",
            :recipient => shipment.supplier.token
          )
          shipment.transferred = true
          shipment.save!
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Since the status key is nested one level in the JSON do I need to account for that in my webhook code? Might it be `case params[:status]` or `case params[:result :status]?`

Thanks

***UPDATE***

I now realize I want to use some more granular details of the EasyPost API. I need to access the status within the array of Tracking Details:

```
//Easypost API
{
"id": "evt_qatAiJDM",
"object": "Event",
"created_at": "2014-11-19T10:51:54Z",
"updated_at": "2014-11-19T10:51:54Z",
"description": "tracker.updated",
"mode": "test",
"previous_attributes": {
  "status": "unknown"
},
"pending_urls": [],
"completed_urls": [],
"result": {
  "id": "trk_Txyy1vaM",
  "object": "Tracker",
  "mode": "test",
  "tracking_code": "EZ4000000004",
  "status": "delivered",
  "created_at": "2014-11-18T10:51:54Z",
  "updated_at": "2014-11-18T10:51:54Z",
  "signed_by": "John Tester",
  "weight": 17.6,
  "est_delivery_date": "2014-08-27T00:00:00Z",
  "shipment_id": null,
  "carrier": "UPS",
  "tracking_details": [
    {
      "object": "TrackingDetail",
      "message": "BILLING INFORMATION RECEIVED",
      "status": "pre_transit",
      "datetime": "2014-08-21T14:24:00Z",
      "tracking_location": {
        "object": "TrackingLocation",
        "city": null,
        "state": null,
        "country": null,
        "zip": null
      }
```

So I need to access `result` and then `tracking_details` and then `status`. this case statement: `case params[:result][:tracking_details][:status]` gave me this error:

```
    May 14 10:31:30 leemaeats app/web.1:  TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer): 
May 14 10:31:30 leemaeats app/web.1:    app/controllers/hooks_controller.rb:28:in `[]' 
May 14 10:31:30 leemaeats app/web.1:    app/controllers/hooks_controller.rb:28:in `stripe'
```

Seems like it's because I need to specify the element in this array `tracking_details`. Anyone know how to reference that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `case params[:result][:status]`

`params[:result]` returns a hash which contains, among other things, the `"status"` member that you can access with `[:status]`

EDIT to answer UPDATE

`params[:result][:tracking_details]` returns an array, so you could try any of the following:

To get the first element:

- `params[:result][:tracking_details][0][:status]`
- `params[:result][:tracking_details].first[:status]`

To get all the elements:

- `params[:result][:tracking_details].map{|x| x[:status]}`

Comment: That sounds pretty good. I can't really test it until tomorrow however, but I think this will work! Thanks.

Comment: I rewrote the case statement to get to a different status value: ```case   params[:result][:tracking_details][:status]``` and I got this error:
```May 14 10:34:02 leemaeats app/web.1:  TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer): 
May 14 10:34:02 leemaeats app/web.1:    app/controllers/hooks_controller.rb:28:in `[]' 
May 14 10:34:02 leemaeats app/web.1:    app/controllers/hooks_controller.rb:28:in `stripe'```

Comment: tracking_details contains an array, not a hash

Comment: Exactly. So how could i reference that? Say I just want the first element in the tracking details array, and within that element I just want to access ```status```. Is it something like ```case params[:result][:tracking_details[0]][:status]```?

Comment: `[:tracking_details][0][:status]` or `[:tracking_details].first[:status]` or to get all the statuses, not just the first: `[:tracking_details.map{|x| x[:status]}`

Comment: Hey man, that worked. Do you want to add it as an answer to this post and I'll check it?